# Is there a way to get the duration of a Youtube playlist using PyTube

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I am writing a Python script which download multiple playlist from YouTube and I need to print the number of video and the duration of each playlist. I am using Playlist() from pytube. I have already get the number of videos.

```py
from pytube import Playlist

playlist = Playlist(url)
playlist.populate_video_urls()
print(len(playlist.video_urls))
```

I want that the output will look like:

`NumberOfVideosInThatPlaylist: DurationOfThePlaylist`

Comment: If you can't get playlist length directly than you can fetch each video lenght from its URL available and then total it as playlist duration.

Comment: Thank you @Dave123! I will do it like this